# Disabling vim's -- INSERT -- message

Tags: vim, macvim

When I go to insert mode, vim displays `-- INSERT --` below my status bar (happens with all modes of course, just showing an example):

[image]

Given I'm already showing the current mode in my status bar, is there a way to disable this `-- INSERT --` for pure aesthetics?

I've been diving in the help sections and google, but couldn't find a way. Is this possible, or should I learn to live with it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is controlled by the `showmode` setting. Add

```
set noshowmode
```

to your vimrc to disable the message. The help for `:h 'showmode'` is copied below.

```
                                 'showmode' 'smd' 'noshowmode' 'nosmd'
'showmode' 'smd'        boolean (Vim default: on, Vi default: off)
                        global
        If in Insert, Replace or Visual mode put a message on the last line.
        Use the 'M' flag in 'highlight' to set the type of highlighting for
        this message.
        When XIM may be used the message will include "XIM".  But this
        doesn't mean XIM is really active, especially when 'imactivatekey' is
        not set.
        NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
        set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
```